# SFTP error#3: Permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, sftp

Till yesterday login to our Ubuntu-20.04 LTS was working fine, But today suddenly it started showing below error while trying to login.

> SFTP error#3: Permission denied

```
$ ls
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
```

We have not modified any settings then Why do i get "permission denied" even when user has sudo privileges?

Have tried to change the permisison using below command, however didn't help.

```
chown -R devuser:devuser /home/devuser
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below command helped to solve the issue.

```
chmod 775 /home/devuser
```

It was a permission issue, therefore with above
command able to get ride.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).